# Shared group folder permissions trouble

Tags: linux, permissions

I am creating a shared folder for users in the 'development' group. I am having trouble coming up with a series of commands to use to do this  I need to set the following permissions:

- Only members of the development group can create files in it
- Users can only delete the files and directories they create
- Any new files/folders in the shared directory are associated with the group
- Group owner can only read
- Owner can read files, but others cannot have r/w access

What series of commands could I use to accomplish this?
 I just cannot seem to get this right with chmod and , and when I login as my other users I keep on getting permission denied for viewing the folder or creating files even with sticky bit set.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general system config issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Angellic Chords,

first you must state in your request if you have **root** privileges (login,sudo) to manipulate permissions in the filesystem.

Now you need split task into smaller blocks:

a. add users into developer group (dev_group - assumed already exists)

```
root# for user in (user1 user2 user3 ... usern)
do
    usermod -a -G dev_group $user
done
```

b. create developer group directory

```
mkdir /some/path/to/developer/group/dir
```

c. assign permission on the folder: see [doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)

> - owner root.dev_group (root)
> - owner rwx -- can read, create, change into directory
> - group rwx -- can read, create, change into directory
> - other/world r-x -- can read, change into directory only (check if this desirable)
> - set SGID - newly created files/directories inherit group from directory
> - set 'stiky' bit - allows manipulate only own files/directories

```
chown root.dev_group [path to directory]     # owner root.dev_group
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx [path to directory]   # user rwx; group rwx; other r-x
chmod g+s [path to directory]                # SGID bit inherit group from directory for new files and directories
chmod +t [path to directory]                 # stiky bit manipulate own files and directories only
```

or

```
chmod 3775 [path to directory]
```

**NOTE:** execute permission on a directory allows to change into the directory

d. define [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) for each user:

> - user rwx
> - group r--
> - other ---

(in shell initialisation scripts as .bashrc .profile ....)

```
umask u=rwx,g=r,o=
```

**NOTE:** if umask must be different for any valid reason, then user has to change permission at creation, copy time on new files/directories

More grained access restrictions can be achieved with access control lists [acl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) and [SELinux contexts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/chap-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts).

Comment: Almost correct, but couple of comments: (1) directory owner don't must to be `root`: eg `sudo chown nobody:dev_group` will be fine. (2) to gain owner's read-only access to the directory: `chmod u-w`

Comment: @Sasha Khapyorsky - (1) as OP did not specified who will be responsible for _maintaining order_ I assumed _root_ as user who will _manage permissions_. `nobody` can be used as well. (2) not fully understand your comment, why would user want only read access if he will be creating/modifying/deleting/copying files and directories?

Comment: @Sasha Khapyorsky - (2) `chmod go-w` would make more sense. If OP would say that each user should have own directory in shared directory, then `chmod 755 user_dir` (user full access, group change/read, other change/read). I would do `find user_dir -t d -exec chmod 755 \{}`, `find user_dir -t f -exec chmod 644 \{}` (assumes not executable programs, group and other have read permission on files).

Comment: (2) was in the original question;

Comment: @Sasha Khapyorsky - the sentence **Owner can read files, but others cannot have r/w access** might mean how you understood it, but in this case if would defeat meaning **shared folder**, in my understanding **shared** means that people in the group can **share** or read files of each other. With permission `chmod 400 files` converts folder into **private storage** instead.